# The video from the core data is not displayed

Tags: swift

in swift UIKit

Via PHPickerViewController

Choose the video and store it in the core data successfully

```
result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { url, err in
            do {
                if let urls = url {
                    
                    let localURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(urls.lastPathComponent)
                    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: localURL)
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: urls, to: localURL)
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {

                        coreDateHelperMedia().storeMedia(urlImg: UIImage.init(), videoURL: urls, types: "video")
                        self.collection.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("Error",error)
            }
        }
```

This is the url

```
- _url : file:///Users/badrshammry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7986A27F-7026-45E1-9073-78CCD6A9B90A/data/Containers/Data/Application/E0C76BFB-16C0-4C65-A80C-9D931FFC1EB9/tmp/8bbab7eb-1530-46b2-8bfa-6e9d9262354e.mp4
```

And when you press it in cell in didSelectItemAt
This url comes from the core data

```
- _url : file:///Users/badrshammry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7986A27F-7026-45E1-9073-78CCD6A9B90A/data/Containers/Data/Application/E0C76BFB-16C0-4C65-A80C-9D931FFC1EB9/tmp/.com.apple.Foundation.NSItemProvider.ZUVWZt/8bbab7eb-1530-46b2-8bfa-6e9d9262354e.mp4
```

Here I am playing the video

```
let dataUrl = arrS1[indexPath.row]
        let urlvideo = dataUrl.videoSection?.absoluteString

guard let url = URL(string: urlvideo!) else {return}
            let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath:url.path))
            playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerController.player = player
            playerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
            playerController.delegate = self
            present(playerController, animated: true) {
                player.play()
            }
```

The problem is that it is stuck in the process of running

[image]

[image]

the coreDateHelperMedia()

```
//MARK: - Store
func storeMedia (urlImg : UIImage , videoURL : URL , types : String){
    
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MediaEntity", in: context)
    let coreDataObject = NoteEntity(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    coreDataObject.setValue(urlImg, forKey: "img")
    coreDataObject.setValue(videoURL, forKey: "video")
    coreDataObject.setValue(types, forKey: "typeString")
    coreDataObject.setValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
    do {
        try context.save()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
//MARK: - Fetch

func fetchMedia ()->[MediaModel]{

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return []
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "MediaEntity")
    var items : [MediaModel] = []
    do {
        items.removeAll()
        let coreDataObjects = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for item in coreDataObjects {

            var textItem = MediaModel.init()

            let image = item.value(forKey: "img")
            let video = item.value(forKey: "video")
            let type = item.value(forKey: "typeString")
            let uid = item.value(forKey: "id")

            if let vid = video ,let img = image , let udidd = uid {
                textItem.img = img as! UIImage
                textItem.video = vid as! URL
                textItem.typeString = type as! String
                textItem.id = udidd as! UUID

                items.append(textItem)
            }
        }
        return items
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: What does `coreDateHelperMedia()` do?

Comment: I added it at the end of the topic

Comment: "This url comes from the core data" Nope, you cannot save an absolute file URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494774/avplayer-playerwithurl-not-working-after-app-restart

Answer (score 1):

A video is a bunch of `Data` or in practise a file in the file system. You aren't storing any video to your database. You are storing a `URL` that references a file in a temporary directory which you actively did by choosing `FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory`. That directory is temporary and doesn't survive long.

What you need to do is:

1. Copy the video to your apps document directory where it will remain persistent over multiple app launches.
2. Store a reference to the video as a relative URL. Store the name of the video in core data and rebuild the entire URL each time you want it.

You can always locate the app document directory via `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` e.g:

```
enum AppURLS {
  static func documentsDirectory() -> URL {
    guard let docspath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last else {
      fatalError("unable to get system docs directory - serious problems")
    }
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: docspath)
  }
}
```

And your storage function will look like this:

```
func storeMedia (videoURL : URL) {
    let name = videoURL.lastPathComponent 
    let note = NoteEntity(etc)
    note.video = name //only store name
    
    let target = AppURLS.documentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(name)
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: videoURL, to: target)
}
```

When you want the video back again use the name stored in the video property to rebuild the source URL and give that to your video player.